# Content alignment in label WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, label

i have a small problem with the alignment of my text in a label

this is my xaml code

```
<GroupBox Header="Normal" Width="450" Height="150" Name="grpNormal">
    <Canvas Name="cvsNormal" Width="440" Height="140">
        <Label Name="lblStartRegNormal" Width="223" Content="Enter the starting reg number: " FontSize="16" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        <TextBox Name="txtStartRegNormal" Height="40" Width="200" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="15"/>
        <Label Name="lblEndRegNormal" Width="223" Content="Enter the ending reg number: " FontSize="16" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="65" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtEndRegNormal" Height="40" Width="200" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="65"/>
    </Canvas>
</GroupBox>
```

here is the output

[image]

but when i change my label content, the colons on the right side are not aligned

[image]

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using a canvas as layout container? If so, that is what is wrong here, use a Grid

Comment: please share full XAML-Code ;-)

Comment: @sine i edited my question with the full XAML code

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Okay, i will try using a Grid. But where should a canvas be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Snoop WPF](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to examine your running application you will find that the Labels Visual Tree includes a Border element width a padding of 5,5,5,5.

If you remove the padding using SnoopWPF everything renders fine.  This indicates that whilst the label width is 223 the width for the text content is less and its stretching into this padding on the longer text. Try making the label slightly wider or just using a TextBlock instead.

Comment: That worked great. I just had to increase the width of the label.

Answer (score 7):

```
<GroupBox Header="Normal" Width="450" Height="150" Name="grpNormal">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Name="lblStartRegNormal" Width="223" Content="Enter the starting reg number: " FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBox Name="txtStartRegNormal" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" Width="200"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1"  Name="lblEndRegNormal" Width="223" Content="Enter the ending reg number: " FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtEndRegNormal" Height="40" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

It looks like this:

[image]